# Why doesn't my iphone install seem to finish?

Tags: ios, iphone, firemonkey

I have an iPhone app that compiles and works fine in the simulator. However when I try to sideload it as an Ad Hoc application, the install seems to fail silently.

Initially when it's trying to sync to the phone, it gets the grey icon (as expected), and I get a install sweep / radar over lay on it.

It gets to about 80% (10 o'clock) and then disappears. The icon remains grey and the title says "Waiting". If I later try to run the application the title changes to "Installing..."

iOS: 8.4
Xcode: 6.4
Embarcadero/FireMonkey: XE8

Comment: It's seems a certificate problem. Are you sure your device is added to provisioning profile device list ?

Comment: I've managed to side load a native app (Swift) on the phone, so I think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging in further... by looking at the Console for my iPhone in Xcode

> Window -> Devices -> (phone) -> little triangle button on the bottom left of the Device Information panel.

The listed error has now scrolled past the end of the buffer so I can't post an example; but as I recall it was this [one](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2319/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013778-CH1-ERRORMESSAGES-DEVICE_UDID_MISSING_FROM_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_RELATED_INSTALL_FAILURES) that clued me in to what happened:

`profile not valid: <hex_identifier>`

I was able to determine that it was indeed the provisioning profile that was the problem.

Back in the Embarcadero/FireMonkey side of the equation, the Mobile Provision and Developer Certificate settings were missing/reverted to defaults.

> Project -> Options -> Provisioning

Near as I can tell, because I have a couple different sets of certificates on my Mac, the ones that are set as the default are broken/missing devices and I needed to explicitly specify the good one.

Comment: If this actually solved your problem then you may mark this answer as accepted. It may help others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: I plan to. I've got to wait two days for that to happen. UNLESS someone else wants to come up with another answer with an awesome explanation I can mark accepted.

Comment: Ok, sorry then. I didn't knew you've to wait to accept your own answer.